# jquery swap/animate array of sequential jpg images

Tags: jquery, image, animation, swap

I am trying to swap/animate preloaded jpg images using the following to preload the images:

```
<img id="slideshow" src="../../Content/images/IM0-Frame1.jpg" alt="" width="200"
        height="200">
    <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    preload_images();
                  });
                function preload_images() {
                    var images = new Array();
                    for (var i = 1; i <= 126; i++) {
                        var str;
                        if (i < 10) {
                            str = i;
                        } else {
                            str = i;
                        }
                          images.src="../Content/images/IM0-Frame" + str + ".jpg";
                    }
                }
    </script>
```

I would appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simple slideshow, it preloads images, slide them with the `setInterval` function and on mouse over/leave it stops/resumes looping the images:

```js
var images = [];
var i = 0;
var interval = null;

function preload_images() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 126; i++) {
        images[i] = new Image();
        images[i].src = "../Content/images/IM0-Frame" + i + ".jpg";
    }
}

preload_images();

function cycle_images() {
    i = (i < 2) ? i + 1 : 0;
    document.getElementById('slideshow').src = images[i].src;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    interval = setInterval(cycle_images, 2000);
    $('#slideshow').hover(function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }, function() {
        interval = setInterval(cycle_images, 2000);
    });
});
```

[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/zmSw5/)

Comment: It did help alot, thanks.  Just two questions if you would not mind.  First when the animation reaches the last image I get error in this line "i = (i < 2) ? i + 1 : 0;"  Can't find scr.  the second is will it be possible to make hover to a button click.  Like start and stop button.  Thanks again.

Comment: Oh yeah it is a typo and it should be `i = (i<126)? i+1:0;`. What is it can't find scr.? Are you looking for something like [jQuery carousel](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+carousel)? - [Plugins are here](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/06/jquery-carousel.html)

Comment: Imho it is not so simple to make a cool clickable links menu for 126 pictures :)

Comment: You are right, carousel function is what I am looking for; your solution works great, except I get error in this line document.getElementById('slideshow').src = images[i].src;
after the last image is displayed.  I need to make it loop.  Thanks a million

Comment: @user373721 That element should be an image tag. Also thank you and have a good time :)

Comment: Thanks, it was my mistake I should have used 125 instead of 126.  Now all is done, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually pre-loading the images, just filling an array with their urls, to preload an image create an Image object an set its src property to the image url.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "../Content/images/IM0-Frame" + str + ".jpg";
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea how I can change the images!

Comment: Thank Musa, I get this error Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'nextimage' is undefined

Comment: @user373721 nextimage represents the next image in the slideshow, you have to assign it a value.